# javascript while loop print after loop done

Tags: javascript, loops, object, while-loop

so here is what I want to do:

Two objects have hp and power variables. I want to do sort of a battle between them. The logic is do a loop which does like this: object1HP-object2Power, Object2HP - Object2Power. When HP of one of the objects is 0 or below - print who won.

this is what I have so far:

```js
 this.battle = function(other) {
     do {
           this.hp - other.power;
           other.hp - this.power;
        }
     while (this.hp <=0 || other.hp <=0);
        
        if(this.hp <=0) {
            console.log(this.name + " won!");
        } else {
            console.log(other.name + " won!");
        }
   }
```

I know this might be a mess. Thanks!

Comment: you need to change your loop to be and (&&) and > 0 so it continues until one is below or equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. Does the code snippet work?
One tiny detail that springs to my eye is, that you probably want to write

```
this.hp -= other.power;
other.hp -= this.power;
```

You are missing the "=", and you get an infinite loop, because the variables stay unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the working code snippet:

```js
this.battle = function(other) {
     do {
           this.hp = this.hp - other.power; //Need to set this.hp equal to it, or nothing is changing
           other.hp = other.hp - this.power;
        }
     while (this.hp >=0 && other.hp >=0); //You want to keep running the loop while BOTH players have HP above 0
        
        if(this.hp <=0) { //If this has less than zero HP, then the other person won, so you need to inverse it
            console.log(other.name + " won!");
        } else {
            console.log(this.name + " won!");
        }
   }
```

The first issue you had was that you weren't setting your variables after you changed them. Just having `this.hp - other.power` doesn't save the value into any variable. So `this.hp` remains the same after each loop. In order to fix this, just set the new value into `this.hp` by saying `this.hp = this.hp - other.power`.

Second issue is that your condition for your while loop was incorrect. Saying `this.hp <= 0 || other.hp <= 0` is saying "if either player has hp less then zero, keep running" where as what you're looking for is "if both players have hp greater than zero, keep running"

Finally, your logic in the final `if` statement was wrong. I added some comments on the code snippet to walk you through the changes.
Let me know if something is still wrong, hope this helped.